# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery was not found

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm deploying a asp.net core 2.0 website to IIS 10.

I've made sure that my app is using the correct configuration for ISS in the program.settings file.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

And in my startup.cs file:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
        });
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Yet when I run dotnet website.dll from the command line I get the below error message shown in the command line window:

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest
>   (website.deps.json) was not found:
>       package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.1'
>       path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'   This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the
>   application was published using the following target manifest files:
>       aspnetcore-store-2.0.3.xml

Based off the error message, i'm guessing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery isn't being bundled when I publish since I do not receive this error when debugging.

How can I ensure that my app can find Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery when published to a live environment?

EDIT: This is a basic .net core website. No changes have been made to the standard project at this time apart from the above changes for deployment with IIS.

When I run the project from IIS instead of the command line I get a 502.5 error message.

Comment: Try `dotnet restore`. If this not help use temporary solution and just copy this *.dll from local to deploy

Comment: As @J.Doe mentioned, try a `dotnet restore`. Would you also mind sharing your csproj?

Comment: If you publish in Windows (other somewhere other than your server) and run in Linux, then make sure both .Net SDK's version are the same or compatible. You can check their versions with `dotnet --info` or `dotnet --version`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by updating the .net core runtime on the server to v2.0.3.

This issue occurs if

1. You have an existing server running v2.0.0 of the .net core runtime.
2. You create an app targeting v2.0.3 of the SDK
3. You publish the v2.0.3 app to a server running v2.0.0

The issue can be resolved by installing v2.0.3 of the runtime on the server. You can download the runtime from the microsoft site here https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Comment: Alternatively, you can revert to an earlier .NET Core Nuget package.  I had to install 2.0.0 because the Pivotal Cloud Foundry buildpack I was pushing to was at 2.0.0 and my build was using 2.0.3.

Comment: There is a "ASP.NET Core Runtime" and a ".NET Core Runtime". Only the ASP version solved the issue for me (v2.0.7 worked). Also, on the download page you first have to click the "Run apps" button, to access these downloads.

Comment: In my case I needed to change the base image in Dockerfile from aspnetcore:2.0 to aspnetcore:2.0.8 because I was referencing Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.8 which required Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery >= 2.0.3.

Answer (score 11):

If you are actually using this library, make sure that your *.csproj file has the corresponding explicit reference:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery" Version="..." />
```

Then, play with the **PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest** property to resolve the aforementioned issue with a mismatched manifest.
Check out the following threads to learn more about possible issues while its deployment:

[An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (RhWeb.deps.json) was not found](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13542)

[published application is missing assembly (missing runtime store associated ...) [2.0.0-preview2-005905]](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6516)

[HTTP Error 502.5 - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/476)

Comment: Adding the PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest property with value false appears to work for me. i did notice the additional files included with a publish. It appears it makes the application wholly self-contained?

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue - simple workaround, actually install the NuGet package (I wasn't using it).

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery

Published, deployed - fixed the issue.

In another case, when I published the project, a lot of the dlls weren't being placed in the publish folder - including Antiforgery. The below appears to force publishing to add all the required dlls.

Edit your projectname.json file to ensure `PropertyGroup` contains `PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest = false`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Interested to know why the above works?!

Comment: Thanks! Made simple the dependency nightmare I got myself in with different projects using different versions of dotnet on an old VPS.

Answer (score 3):

This also problem happens  if Antiforgery is called but Antiforgery is not installed.

Can be fixed by installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery by Nuget package manager.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue on my inhouse windowsserver with this solution
* go to netcore https://github.com/dotnet/core/tree/master/release-notes
* go to the lastest version of the core runtime 2.?
* download DotNetCore.2.0.6-WindowsHosting.exe in my case
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.6-download.md#net-core-runtime-only-installation

Install this on server and the error was solved for me. Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Got this error after updating `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` from v2.0.7 to v2.0.8 (latest at the time) and then publishing to a server that was running .NET Core Runtime v2.0.7 (latest at the time).

Downgraded `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` back down to v2.0.7, re-published, and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

If you publish the app as a self-contained ASP.NET Core 2.2 apps as per the linked screenshot (I don't have enough rep for inline image), it will fix this issue.

Self contained:
[image: Screenshot]

This can be set when editing your publish settings.

Answer (score 0):

If this issue is related to your Razor mail template, you can add "**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation**". When I add, the problem is solved.